# Removing nan rows from a dataframe in columns excluding a set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am aware of the function DataFrame.dropna(subset), where subset argument can be used to remove nan rows only from the given set of columns. 
What I want is to remove nan rows from columns excluding a set of columns. Is there a way to do this in pandas ?

Comment: Somthing like: `df.columns.difference(exclude_cols)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with list of columns for exclude:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=df.columns.difference(exclude_columns)))
```